# iOs build failed in codemagic VM : Error (Xcode): 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, release, codemagic

I'm newer on flutter and on mobile dev in general.

In local machine, I can successfully build the iOS debug version on the iOS simulator, and the application launches correctly. However, when I attempt to build the release version using Codemagic's workflow, I encounter the following issues:

```
Saved export options to /Users/builder/export_options.plist

> flutter build ipa --release --export-options-plist /Users/builder/export_options.plist
Resolving dependencies...
  audio_video_progress_bar 0.11.0 (2.0.1 available)
  awesome_notifications 0.8.2 (0.9.0 available)
! dio 5.4.0 (overridden)
  firebase_auth 4.15.3 (4.16.0 available)
  fl_chart 0.65.0 (0.66.0 available)
! flutter_dio_http_cache 0.3.1 (overridden)
  flutter_inappwebview 5.8.0 (6.0.0 available)
  google_api_headers 2.0.3 (3.7.0 available)
  intl 0.18.1 (0.19.0 available)
  jiffy 6.2.1 (6.2.2 available)
  matcher 0.12.16 (0.12.16+1 available)
  material_color_utilities 0.5.0 (0.8.0 available)
! meta 1.11.0 (overridden)
  package_info_plus 4.2.0 (5.0.1 available)
  path 1.8.3 (1.9.0 available)
! photo_manager 3.0.0-dev.5 (overridden)
  syncfusion_flutter_calendar 23.2.7 (24.1.44 available)
  syncfusion_flutter_core 23.2.7 (24.1.44 available)
  syncfusion_flutter_datepicker 23.2.7 (24.1.44 available)
  test_api 0.6.1 (0.7.0 available)
  web 0.3.0 (0.4.0 available)
! win32 5.2.0 (overridden)
Got dependencies!
17 packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints.
Try `flutter pub outdated` for more information.

Archiving ag.amaya.farmer...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: ********
Running pod install...                                            305.5s
Running Xcode build...                                          
Xcode archive done.                                         290.4s
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
/Users/builder/clone/farmer/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h:9:8

Error (Xcode): failed to emit precompiled header '/Users/builder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-cwhdghwkfsecylfzzbdiegifniyg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/PrecompiledHeaders/Runner-Bridging-Header-swift_1OA4SU7K8SZ1N-clang_1ELA9HQ0UON1L.pch' for bridging header '/Users/builder/clone/farmer/ios/Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h'

Encountered error while archiving for device.

Build failed
```

Before successfully building locally, I encountered the same error. However, I resolved it by cleaning the project, rebuilding the iOS folder (with the Runner backup), and the problem disappeared.

On Codemagic, I accessed the VM remotely to attempt the same steps, but the result remains negative.

Flutter doctor output:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.5, on macOS 14.2 23C64 darwin-arm64, locale en-FR)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.84.1)
```

The same configuration is present on the Codemagic machine."

thanks in advance

I'm trying to build my flutter application release version for iOs using codemagic
build is failed : Error (Xcode): 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found

I'm expecting a successful build for release iOs version